# Flash CC on OS X: Where is the ActionScript 3.0 library?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cc

For the life of me, I can't find the AS3 lib. I know in Flash CS6, I can find it at:
/Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs

I need to point my IDE at it, and the company I'm at can ONLY use Flash CC going forward (Corporate reasoning), and I'm the first one on the team to have to use Flash CC. My workaround is to use a trial version of CS6, but I'd like to figure this out.

Flash CC supports AS3, so the library has to be somewhere, right? If not, how does it function without it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's inside the app package:

/Applications/Adobe Flash CC 2015/Adobe Flash CC 2015.app/Contents/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs

To navigate to this folder, right click on the Adobe Flash CC 2015.app and choose "Show Package Contents".

Comment: Thanks so much! I never would have thought of trying this. :)